# randomly choosing from a deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Suppose I have a deck of 26 black and 26 red cards. I randomly choose 26 cards from this deck and I look at the first two cards. What is the probability that both cards are black?

I think the probability is 
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{25}{51} = \frac{25}{102}$$ since we are choosing 26 cards randomly and this is equivalent to having a total deck. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Choosing the 26 cards randomly and checking the first two cards is same as checking the first two cards from the deck. The answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

wrong
there are two cases

first, withdrawing with replacement
will be
26/52*26/52=0.25

Secondly, withdrawing without replacement
will be
26/52*25/51=0.245

Answer (score 0):

YES!

The experiment is like picking one card at random from the deck, and then another.

How likely are both black?  Use the rule that says P(A and B) = P(A)P(B|A) where
A and B are the probabilities that the first is black, and that the second is black.

How likely is it that the first is black?  1/2

Given that the first is black, how likely is it that the second draw is too?  only
51 cards left, of which 25 are black... 25/51.